# how to fix and center image on div

Tags: html, css

I want to fix my background image in the center of my container so that if I scroll or zoom in, my image does not re-scale or cut. Also, how can I center my login div without having any problems? When I put `margin: 100px auto` to it, it makes my page scrollable and when I scroll and zoom my page, the margin blocks some parts of my image. Any ideas?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="login">
    </div>  
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
body, html {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#container {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background: url(images/bg-admin.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
}

.login {
    margin:100px auto;
    width:400px;
    padding:1em;
    background:white;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 6px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 6px #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px #ccc;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `margin: 0 auto;`?

Answer (score -1):

Apologies for the partial answer but for fixed background you can use the `background-attachment` property and give it a value of `fixed`.

Comment: Look at their short-hand 'background' style again, it already has that.